# Not iterating through array

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to get this code to go through each item in computers and display the requested information. But it is only outputting the last item. Not sure what I need to change.

```
#powershell script for disk space monitoring 
#Array to hold list of Servers
$computers = @("dsmsql2","dsmfs2","dsmgmc2")

#Iterate through each server
foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
   #Place the above code inside

$percentWarning = 80; # Store the percentage warning threshold
$disks = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 3";
$mailbody = "The following drive(s) have less than $percentWarning% free sapce in Server: $computer`n`n";
$mailbody+="Drive`t`tTotalspace(GB)`t`t`Freespace(GB)`n --------------------------------------------------------------- `n";
$drivedata=[string]::Empty;
$emailsubject="$computer - Low Disk Space Alert!";
}

# Code to send email to the SharePoint Administrator/Group
function SendEmail([string]$msg)
{
    $SMTPClient = new-object System.Net.Mail.smtpClient;
    $SMTPClient.host = ""
    $MailMessage = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage;
    $MailMessage.Subject = $emailsubject;
    $MailMessage.Body = $msg;
    $MailMessage.From = "";
    $MailMessage.To.add("");
    $SMTPClient.Send($MailMessage);
}

#The following block performs the core functionality
foreach($disk in $disks) 
{ 
    $deviceID = $disk.DeviceID; 
    [float]$size = $disk.Size; 
    [float]$freespace = $disk.FreeSpace;   
    $percentFree = [Math]::Round(($freespace / $size) * 100, 2); 
    $sizeGB = [Math]::Round($size / 1073741824, 2); 
    $freeSpaceGB = [Math]::Round($freespace / 1073741824, 2);   
    if($percentFree -lt $percentWarning) 
    { 
        $drivedata += "$deviceID`t`t $sizeGB`t`t`t$freeSpaceGB`n";
    } 
}

#Email to be sent only if any drive has free space less than the threshold value
if($drivedata.length -gt 0)
{
    $msg=$mailbody+$drivedata;
    SendEmail($msg);
}
```

`your text`
It's supposed to output data for each server that meets the threshold. However, it's only outputting the last item. I feel like it's missing something but not sure what. *Note* I removed email addresses for privacy.`your text`

Comment: Your `foreach ($disk in $disks) { ... }` loop and the `if($drivedata.length -gt 0) { ... }` statement belong inside your `foreach ($computer in $computers) { ... }` loop.

Comment: That helped get it to look at each server. But I'm wanting everything in one email too. It sent one for each server.

Comment: You'll need to restructure your code to collect the messages either in an array whose elements you join later to form a single string, or build up a single large string with `+=`. Then make sending contingent on whether you have array element / a non-empty result string. You'll also need to think about how to handle the subject line, given that it currently mentions a single server.

Comment: I will make those adjustments. Thank you for the help!